# DigitalPersona DPFPEnrollmentControl no longer works

Tags: delphi, fingerprint

I had a Delphi XE application using the DigitalPersona U.are.U Fingerprint Reader. It worked just fine last month. Now the DPFPEnrollmentControl no longer works. The DPFPVerificationControl works just fine.

I had a form with the design time DPFPEnrollmentControl Active X control. Now on opening that form it says the control no longer exists. So I instead created the control at design time. Now I get the exact same problem. When trying to assign fingerprints, when you click on a finger nothing happens. You can't scan in any fingerprints.

Any ideas of what could have happened? I didn't install any new controls. All that changed recently were some Windows updates. I have no code to show because it's nothing to do with my code but the control itself.

Comment: What is the *exact error* you're seeing when *opening that form*?

Comment: Class: TDPFPEnrollmentControl not found. Ignore the error and continue?

Comment: The IDE doesn't know about the component. Check the package list (in *Components->Install Components* from the main menu) and see if the package containing that component is there and is checked.

Comment: Got called away and my effort to edit my last comment timed out. If the component isn't in that dialog, you'll need to reinstall it. (If you can find the design time package (`.BPL`) it was in, you can use the *Add* button to just install that package; otherwise, you'll need to actually add it to a package and install that package just like any other component.)

Comment: OK thanks Ken, I did manage to rebuild and reinstall the bpl. For some reason the entire Active X component group was removed. Now I don't get the component error. The demo app I have now works perfectly. My app still does not fire DPFPEnrollmentControl1OnEnroll however.

Comment: Are you sure the event is connected to the event handler? (Check the Object Inspector event tab with your component selected.) Often when a component isn't located like this, and you fix that problem, you forget to reattach the event handlers to the code properly (at least I do).

Comment: No it's weirder than that. I've tried assigning the event at run-time and design-time. I've even tried adding the component form from the working demo app in the main app and it doesn't work. Something in the project is interfering with the Active X control's OnEnroll event.

Comment: Well, I don't have your code, and don't have the control, so I'm afraid I can't help. (I don't have a fingerprint scanner, either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the TDPFPVerificationControl interferes with the TDPFPEnrollmentControl when it is active. I had added a TDPFPVerificationControl on the main form. When I set DPFPVerificationControl.Active:= False, open the form containing the TDPFPEnrollmentControl then set DPFPVerificationControl.Active:= True on closing the form, all works again.

Comment: Can you please send me the source code of your application to test it ?